# Como mandar un parámetro por un onClick en aspx

Tags: asp.net, aspx

En una página tengo 2 botones, ambos abren el mismo aspx (una página que tiene 2 dropdownlist), lo que quiero es que al dar click al boton1, me abra el aspx con los 2 dropdownlist habilitados y cuando de click al boton2 me abra el aspx con sólo uno de los 2 dropdownlist habilitados.

Les agradezco de antemano.

Comment: Lo resolví de otra manera, de igual manera si alguien quiere responder esa duda, se agradece. Saludos1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal vez la mejor manera sería que en lugar de ser dos botones sean dos links que apunten al ASPX, pero en el link agregale algún parámetro, algo así:

```
<a href="mipagina.aspx?b=1">botón 1</a>
<a href="mipagina.aspx?b=2">botón 1</a>
```

Después, en la página que tiene que mostrar los DropDownList podés leer el parámetro pasado con algo así:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string boton = Request.QueryString.Get("b");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(boton))
        DropDownList1.Visible =
            DropDownList2.Visible = false;
    else
        switch (boton)
        {
            case "1":
                DropDownList1.Visible =
                    DropDownList2.Visible = true;
                break;
            case "2":
                DropDownList1.Visible = false;
                DropDownList2.Visible = true;
                break;
            default:
                DropDownList1.Visible =
                    DropDownList2.Visible = false;
                break;
        }
}
```

Espero te sirva.
¡Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una funcion en javascript

```
<input type="button" onclick="funcion(parametro);">
```

```js
funcion(parametro){
//code
}
```